# Is there any method in django to use database without creating models.py file?

Tags: python, django, model

I am having a database with some data filled in it and i want to use it in my new django app. So is their any way to use data of database in my django app.Actually i don't want to make any changes in my old database and only want to use its data. Anybody please suggest me what will be the better approach to do this.

While serching i also found a command-`inspectdb`
 which can generate model.py file from database, but their are some issues with it that it does'nt map the foreign key in model.py, we need to rearrange our classes in model.py file and some more. So i am searching for some other alternative.

Comment: there's not much point using Django if you don't create models to match your db data.  you should create models using `inspectdb` then edit them manually until they work

Comment: If the problem is just that inspectdb doesn't recognise the foreign key field, you just have to change the definition in your model, that's all.

Comment: As @Anentropic said, i'm afraid there is no good alternative to 'inspectdb'. I suggest you to read this article http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter18.html for clean and good manual correction.

Comment: I just want to know if there any other better way to do this and If inspectdb is the best way i will definitely go with it.Thanks all.

Comment: Still i stuck in other problem that i am having two databases and on running inpectdb command it create model.py file with default db. Is there any way so that i can specify another database name in that command.

Comment: Please also tell me , as i am having two database configured in my django setting,py file then should i need two model.py files or one?

Comment: @juree That book was written for Django 1.0. It's better to use the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/legacy-databases/).

Comment: Thanks @juree .Its really helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could access data from legacy database using connection.cursor() from django.db module.

If you have two dabases

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'new_database',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': ''
    },
    'old': {
        'NAME': 'old_database',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': ''
    }
}
```

...

```
from django.db import connections
cursor = connections['old'].cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT...")
cursor.fetchall()
```

refer to docs:

[Executing custom SQL directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)

[Multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/)

But if you want to modify data in your old database it is better idea to create models.py file and use it as always. Using inspectdb or not is up to you. For example you cold generate model using inpsectdb in separate temporary project, make dumpdata to create json files and upload data to your active project somehow.

Comment: thanks @singer. So by using this i need not to create two model.py files?

Comment: You dont need to. Just access as raw sql your old data, even in another database

Comment: Ok as i dont want to update old database and i just want to use its data so i guess cursors will be best for me. Thanks @singer.