# Creating search form in admin panel - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django.
I created the sqlite3 database called "test.db" and I'm not using the models.py or default database to sync in views.py for saving data. 
I've created the HTML to get the value to store in test.db and print the data using the normal sqlite3 query.
The problem is that I have to access the test.db database in admin panel to search and print the data stored in the database. How to do this task?

Comment: Form → view → query → output template

Comment: Could you please elebrate.. I do not understand thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set up models.py for you to see data in admin functionality of the site. This is because the register statement `register(*models, site=django.admin.sites.site)` uses the models to display the data. If you are working on legacy database which you aren't, in this case, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833769/is-there-any-method-in-django-to-use-database-without-creating-models-py-file)

Comment: Thanks ..could please tell me how to create a form in administration panel and show the result in there..

Comment: You can approach the  problem in two ways, first is to use the forms which are available in Django and it neatly combines with the model you can view the neat tutorial  here - https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_forms/ and the second way is to manually pass values from HTML template to the view sent dex has a nice tutorial here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uGsmuCjZBSU